# How do I change the poptrox-popup vertical-align property in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

How can I change the vertical-align parameter to top in CSS, while still being able to step back a little from the top by N-pixels down? I have already tried all the nodes that are somehow connected with poptrox-popup, nothing works.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add
`top: 30px;`
or
`margin-top: 30px;`

Answer (score 0):

This variant helped me:

```
margin: 0 0 50em 0;

.poptrox-popup {
    background: #1a1f2c;
    background: rgba(18, 21, 29, 0.9);      
    cursor: default;
    /*vertical-align: top;*/ /* Does not work */
    /*top: 30px;*/ /* Does not work */
    /*margin-top: 30em;*/ /* It works, but it shifts down to the bottom */
    margin: 0 0 50em 0; /* It shifts up as I need and rest against the top of the page when the page is resized vertically */
}
```